# i can not calculate second degree Equation

Tags: python

So I wanted to create a Python program to solve a second-degree equation, which tries to find X1 and X2. Here is the code

```
from math import sqrt
import time
a=int(input("Put a First Number:"))
b=int(input("Put a Second Number:"))
c=int(input("Put a Third Number:"))
Delta =pow(b,2)- 4*a*c
OOF=((-1 * b) -sqrt(Delta)) / 2*a 
OOF2=((-1 * b) +sqrt(Delta)) / 2*a  
if Delta <= 0:
    print("Delta=")
    print(Delta)
    time.sleep(2)
    print("There is No Solution")
    print("SR= Ø")
elif Delta == 0:
    print("there is a double solution:")
    print("-b/a:"+ -b/a)
    print("S R ="+ -b/a)
else:
    print("there is 2 Solution:")
    print("X1=-b-squareD/2a="+ OOF)
    print("X2=-b+squareD/2a="+ OOF2)
```

This error popped up

```
OOF=((-1 * b) -sqrt(Delta)) / 2*a
ValueError: math domain error
```

*Any solutions please?*

Comment: is this `Delta =pow(b,2)- 4*a*c` resulting in a negative value?

Comment: You should calculate `OOF` and `OOF2` only if you know that `Delta` is larger than zero.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the calculation of OOF and OOF2 when you are sure the Delta isn't negative otherwise you are trying to calculate square root of a negative number.

```
if Delta <= 0:
    print("Delta= ", Delta) #This looks better
    time.sleep(2)
    print("There is No Solution")
    print("SR= Ø")
elif Delta == 0:
    print("there is a double solution:")
    print("-b/a: ", -b/a) 
    print("S R = ", -b/a) 
else:
    OOF=((-1 * b) -sqrt(Delta)) / 2*a 
    OOF2=((-1 * b) +sqrt(Delta)) / 2*a  
    print("there is 2 Solution:")
    print("X1=-b-squareD/2a= ", OOF) #changed from "X1=-b-squareD/2a="+ OOF
    print("X2=-b+squareD/2a= ", OOF2) #changed from "X2=-b+squareD/2a="+ OOF2
```